# ¿How duplicating a session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli, cart

> I whant to duplicate a session always on when the data be different but with the same identifier (**ID**).

The structure of the database of **products**:

```
id   product  price
1     shirt    30
2     pants    34
```

The structure of the database of the **color** of the products:

```
id   product_id   color
 1      1         blue
 2      1        yellow
 3      2         White
 4      2         black
```

The structure of the database of the **size** of the products

```
id   product_id   size
 1      1          XS
 2      1          S
 3      2          M
 4      2         XL
```

The data (`color` and `size`) are sent by method `POST`

```
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];
```

And `id` of the product by method `GET`.

```
 $itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";
```

I need to duplicate the session of a product to the choose a color or size different.

**Example**

```
-----------------------------------
 Product       Quantity     Price
-----------------------------------
 Shirt blue S      1          30
 Shirt blue XS     1          30
 Shirt yellow S    1          30
```

If we add the same product with the same value (Shirt blue S), update only the quantity.

```
-----------------------------------
 Product       Quantity     Price
-----------------------------------
 Shirt blue S      2          60
```

Not achievement get the duplication of the product, update the same values
selected.

Code **updatecart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";

//SESSION colors
$_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
//SESSION size
$_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
        $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
    }

} else {
    $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
    }
    if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
    } else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
        $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
    }
}
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

Code **cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$itemCount = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
    $meQty = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['qty'] as $meItem){
        $meQty = $meQty + $meItem;
    }
}else{
    $meQty = 0;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) and $itemCount > 0){
    $itemIds = "";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemId){
        $itemIds = $itemIds . $itemId . ",";
    }
    $inputItems = rtrim($itemIds, ",");
    $meSql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ({$inputItems})";
    $meQuery = mysqli_query($kcon, $meSql);
    $meCount = mysqli_num_rows($meQuery);
}else{
    $meCount = 0;
}

if ($meCount == 0){
    echo "<div>No items in the basket</div>";
}else{
?>

    <form action="updatecart.php" method="post" name="fromupdate">            
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $total_price = 0;
    $num = 0;
    while ($meResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meQuery)){
        $key = array_search($meResult['id'], $_SESSION['cart']);
        $total_price = $total_price + ($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]);
        $intemId=$meResult['id'];
        $color = $_SESSION['colors'][$intemId];
        $size = $_SESSION['size'][$intemId];
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td class="cart-image">
    <h3><?php echo $meResult['product']; ?> <?php echo $color; ?> <?php echo $size?></h3>
    </td>
    <td class="cart-price"><?php echo $meResult['price']; ?></td>
    <?php
    $num++;
    }
    ?>                                    
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Help me please, to duplicate the session of a product to the choose a color or size different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use multidimensional array like this it will not overwrite your values.

$_SESSION['colors'][][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];

$_SESSION['size'][][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, and for duplicate the session of a product to the choose a color or size different???

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case **use database instead of session**.
create a table and insert user's different selections and process that table for calculation.huge use of session will be a headache.

Comment: I understand that the huge use of session will be a headache. But create a table not.  At least create a small example in session???